# Django Url Redirection

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, web

I have a problem with my project & I hope that you will help me figure it out.The main problem is that my project is a one-single page template, so I don't have so many views , but I want to know , how to redirect to my homepage

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from iubestete import views as iubestete_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', iubestete_views.index),
    url(r'^',iubestete_views.index,name="portal"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

here is my urls.py file , which function should I import or what should I do? I mean, I want to know for example, if a person types "http://127.0.0.1:8000/adsnjiwadi/" ,how can I redirect that link to my homepage(index.html)?Thank you so much & I hope that you'll have a great day:) Peace:)

Answer (score 0):

Your code `url(r'^',iubestete_views.index,name="portal")` in `urls.py` already catch all URL pattern, it will direct to your home page.

eg: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/adsnjiwadi`, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sfddasfdfaf/ddfsaf`, etc. will go to your home page (index).

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<garbage>.*)/$', views.garbage,name='redirect')
```

In your views.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def garbage(request, garbage):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

This is is a hacky method. Anything other than your root url will return to index url.

Comment: it doesn't work ... or I don't know how to import reverse lol .. anyways, thanks